# Can't use my computer as my LAN default gateway?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I have a home LAN cannect to the internet via an ADSL connection.
My lan consists of two computers(let's pcA and pcB) and an ADSL router.

here's the IPs

router  192.168.1.1
pcA     192.168.1.2
pcB     192.168.1.4

of course both computer use the router's IP as the default gateway.
Now i reconfigured pcA to use pcB as his default gateway(due to a need) but it is not working when I request a web page with my browser!!

can anyone tell me why?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: any more details? OS & how did you configure your interfaces would be a great start

Comment: This is probably better suited at Superuser or Serverfault. Before anyone can help you, you're going to need to give more details. What operating system? How are the machines connected to each other?

Comment: You should try to write your question in proper English, but most of all give more details. How did you do the (re)configuration? Also this is probably not the right forum to address this problem, because here it's all about programming.

Comment: both run windows XP, note here that when I use the router as the default gateway everything works normally, only when I reconfigure pcA to use pcB as gateway( while pcB using the router as gateway) my work dumbs down

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system you may want to :

- Activate internet connection sharing
- Activate the IP forwarding (Example on XP, http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html, or look for iptables on linux)

But a computer does not act as a router if you don't ask him to do so.

Comment: ok, now if I have a proxy server listening on pcB:80...can pcB works as gateway now?

Comment: @user29565, it *can* work as a gateway now, but you need to configure it correctly. The proxy is not relevant. Proxy is not the same thing as router. You need to configure pcB to be a router. Try the links M'vy gave you.

Answer (score 1):

Your pcB is not a router, and it won't route anyway since they are on the same subnet and it has only one interface. If it routed it would redirect pcA to the DSL router anyway, since it's the better path.

What exactly are you trying to do? What is the need?

If you want pcB to be a proxy, you don't configure pcA routing, but configure it's proxy settings to use pcB as it's proxy.

Comment: I tried to configure my browser to use pcB as a proxy on port 80 ( because my proxy is listening on port 80) and it worked perfectly, but now I want to know why it does not work when I configure my proxy as a default gateway to pcA instead of manually configuring the browser

Comment: A proxy works at the application layer and is the endpoint of two TCP connections, your local connection and an outgoing connection. A router is a layer 3, IP network layer, forwarder and requires a complete routing table or a default route. A proxy requires a working network layer to function, but is not required to be in the networks shortest path.